# How to hide div on click outside only

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried to close my div by clicking only outside of div but it also hides itself by clicking child element

```html
<div id="main-container">
  <div id="profile-div">
    <div id="user-pic"></div>
    <span id="user-name">MANISH</span></div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-2x"></i>Dahsbord</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bell fa-2x"></i>Notification</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments fa-2x"></i>Contact us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-2x"></i>Update Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-2x"></i>Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```js
window.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
  var div = document.getElementById("main-container");
  if (e.target != div && e.target.parentNode != div) {
    div.style.left = "-300px";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`parentNode` only gives you the direct parent of the element, in this case if can be ul, li or the inner div. Instead you can use `offsetParent`, which gives you the closest parent that has a non-static position.

```js
 window.addEventListener("mouseup",function(e){
     var div = document.getElementById("main-container");
     if(e.target != div && e.target.offsetParent != div){
   div.style.left ="-300px";
     }
 });
```

```css
#main-container{
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
  <div id="profile-div">
    <div id="user-pic"></div><span id="user-name">MANISH</span></div>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-2x"></i>Dahsbord</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bell fa-2x"></i>Notification</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments fa-2x"></i>Contact us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-2x"></i>Update Account</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-2x"></i>Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

But instead of log.innerHTML = 'OUTSIDE'; you put your line that hides the div

```
<style>
  #main-container {
    border: 1px solid red;

  };
  #profile-div {
    border: 1px solid blue;
  };
</style>
<div id="log"></div>
<div id="main-container">
  <div id="profile-div">
    <div id="user-pic"></div>
    <span id="user-name">MANISH</span>
  </div>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-2x"></i>Dahsbord</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bell fa-2x"></i>Notification</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments fa-2x"></i>Contact us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-2x"></i>Update Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-2x"></i>Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script>
   window.onload = function(e) {
    var div = document.getElementById("main-container");
    var id = "main-container";
    var log = document.getElementById("log");

     window.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
       if( checkParents(e.target, id)) {
         log.innerHTML = 'INSIDE';
       }
       else {
         log.innerHTML = 'OUTSIDE';
       }

     },
     false);

     function checkParents(elm, id) {
       var parent = elm;
       do {
         if(parent.id == id) {
           return true;
         }
         if(parent == window) {
           return false;
         }
       } while(parent = parent.parentNode) ;
     }
   } 
</script>
```